# javascript return function undefined using googlemap API Asynchronous Load

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3

google map api is loaded asynchroneously

```
   jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
});
```

i then do

```
function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);



    var address ="Marseille";

   var geocoder;
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   var markers;
    markers=  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {               
               var titlelatlong=[address,results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng()];                    
              console.log(titlelatlong);    
              return titlelatlong;
             }
      }); 

       console.log(markers);
```

why

```
 console.log(titlelatlong)
```

output is what i want and

```
console.log(markers)
```

is undefined ?

how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

`geocoder.geocode()` is an asynchronous function, while your javascript executes synchronously.

The asynchronous function `geocoder.geocode()` will be called, and then your `console.log(markers)` will be executed, whether or not the previous asynchronous function has finished or not.

Either, assign the variable value in your callback, or use a promise library to wrap your asynchronous code to make it behave like synchronous code.

```
var markers;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {               
        var titlelatlong=[address,results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng()];                    
        markers = titlelatlong; //assign value to variable
        console.log(markers);
    }
});
```

Comment: could u show me how to assign the variable value in my callback in my example ?

Comment: That's what I'm doing with `markers = titleatlong...`! =)

Comment: @DanielB where do you make new google.maps.LatLng() for marker

Comment: @DanielB Kindly help me to solve my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205383/make-geocoder-to-call-synchronously

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps Geocoding API is asynchronous, which means that assigning `marker` to `geocoder.geocode()` will be undefined since the method itself returns nothing.

What `geocoder.geocode()` provides is to consume a callback function which it will call once it finishes running. The Geocoding API will pass data to the callback that you defined, and from there you can obtain the information you need, like the `console.log(titlelatlong)` you printed out.