# make geocoder to call synchronously

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two hidden fields which contain latitude value values and longitude values having id-`#latitude_val and #longitude_val`.I will set variable `chicago` with a initial latitude and longitude.If above two fields are null,I will pass the place name (here statically for checking )and locate the marker by the following  code.

```
function initialize() { 
  chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);//default value
  if(($("#latitude_val").val().length >3) ||   ($("#longitude_val").val().length>3))
   {
   chicago =  new google.maps.LatLng($("#latitude_val").val(), $("#longitude_val").val());  
    }
  else
    { 
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'Abudhabi'}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
      {  
       console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat()+' '+results[0].geometry.location.lng());//if null this should print first
       chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng()); 
      console.log('__'+chicago);//this should print second    
      }
      else
      {
          console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }  
      }); 
   }
   console.log('****'+chicago);//this should print third
   var mapOptions = { zoom:4, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, center: chicago }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);  
   var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:chicago,
    map:map,
   draggable:true,
   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
   });

   marker.setMap(map);
   });
 }
```

I have checked the value of `chicago` in cases.Here the default value is marked by the marker in the map.When I check console,the third one is printing first,the first one in second and second one in third.I didnt understand why this happens.I need to run this based on the order.

The map is showing with values (51.508742,-0.120850) rather than the new values
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, your comments indicating when you expect various values to print are not correct.

Comment: @geocodezip How to make synchronous geocoder??Everything is fine and I only want to make variable get the value in the order of code.

Comment: @geocodezip I didnt understand why you said values printed are incorrect

Comment: Because the thing you say will print third runs first, so will print first.

Comment: How to make it behave like synchronize???.I understood geocoder runs asynchronously.I need to run it synchronously.Pls help me @geocodezip

Comment: There is a reason it is asynchronous.

Comment: @geocodezip can you suggest me to solve my problem

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue and demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I guess you might populate said inputs from the backend, and provide a fallback in case they are null. Either way, you want to get a location and **only then** you want to instance your map.

The following should work:

```
var map;
function initialize() {

  var createMapWithLocation=function(myposition) {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: myposition
      },
      mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions),
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myposition,
        map: mymap,
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
      });
      console.log('****' + myposition); //this should print third
    return mymap;
  };

  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850); //default value
  if (($("#latitude_val").val().length > 3) || ($("#longitude_val").val().length > 3)) {
    chicago = new google.maps.LatLng($("#latitude_val").val(), $("#longitude_val").val());
    map = createMapWithLocation(chicago);
  } else {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': 'Abudhabi'
    }, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat() + ' ' + results[0].geometry.location.lng()); //if null this should print first
        chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        console.log('__' + chicago); //this should print second 
         map = createMapWithLocation(chicago);  
      } else {
        console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

You decide when to call `createMapWithLocation`. It will be synchronous if the inputs are populated, and asynchronous if they aren't. Either way, you don't need to know the position of chicago beforehand.

Please note I've declared map outside of the `initialize` function, just in case you want to inspect it from the console.